# How to make a field required validation rule for multiple record types and if they're of certain profiles?

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I am trying to create a `Validation Rule` that when a user creates a new record or updating and saving existing record. If the `RecordTypeId = "New"` or `RecordTypeId = "Old"` that for multiple profiles the lead source field is required.  How can I add to this validation rule to include the check for `RecordTypeId`?

```
AND(
    CASE(
        $Profile.Name,
        "special",        "Yes",
        "revenue",        "Yes",
        "alt",            "Yes",
        "No"
    ) == "Yes",
    ISBLANK(TEXT(LeadSource))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check for multiple `RecordType` values by referencing `RecordType.DeveloperName`. Note that you can also use a simpler `CASE` function for `Profile`. Using numbers rather than `'Yes'`/`'No'` is easier to read and understand, but more importantly will lower your compile size.

```
AND(
    1 = CASE(
        RecordType.DeveloperName,
        'New', 1, 'Old', 1,
        0
    ),
    1 = CASE(
        $Profile.Name,
        'Special', 1, 'Revenue', 1, 'Alt', 1,
        0
    ),
    ISPICKVAL(LeadSource, '')
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: @user Did you double check that you include the correct `DeveloperName` values? How about `Profile.Name`? You need everything to match verbatim.

Comment: Yes. I did forgot to mention the lead source field is a picklist field

Comment: It doesn't work. How can I  show  you what I have?

Comment: DeveloperName can't have any spaces in it.

Comment: our recordtypes  values are 'Alternative Revenue' and 'Specialty'. The ones in the post are just examples.

Comment: You're pulling in the label not the name. You should use the latter as it is unique.

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you provide an example?